# Hamming Code - Error Detection & Correction

Tags: c

This question builds on a few other posts. I understand if this is not relevant to most of the people on the internet but at this point, just like anyone else, I am stuck and cannot find the bug in logic. This question requires checking a specified hamming code for a single-bit error and report/correct the error. Here is the program to do so:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    /** Initializing the global variables */
    int MaxLength;
    int length;
    int parity;
    // Initialize the hamming string with a random or NULL memory address 
    char *HammingString=NULL;

    /** Function to enter the values */
    void EnterParameters(int *length, int *parity)
    {
        printf("Enter the maximum length: ");
        /** %d reads an integer to be stored in an int. This integer can be signed */
        scanf("%d", length);
        printf("Enter the parity (0=even, 1=odd): ");
        /** %d reads an integer to be stored in an int. This integer can be signed */
        scanf("%d", parity);
    }

    void CheckHamming(char *HammingString, int parity)
    { 
        // Initializing the local variables i, j, k, start, length, ParityNumber  
        int i, j, k, start, length, ParityNumber; 
        printf("Enter the Hamming code: ");
        scanf("%s", HammingString);

        int ErrorBit = 0;                        // Initialize the error bit 
        length = strlen(HammingString);          // The strlen computes the length of a string up to, but not including the terminating null character
        length--;
        if (length > MaxLength)
        {
            printf("\n** Invalid Entry - Exceeds Maximum Code Length of %d\n\n", MaxLength);
            return;
        }
        ParityNumber = ceil(log(length)/log(2)); // The ceil function returns the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to 'x'. 

        for(i = 0; i < ParityNumber; i++)
        {
            // pow returns x raised to the power y. In this case, 2 raised to the power i. 
            start = pow(2, i);
            int ParityCheck = parity; 

            for(j = start; j < length; j=j+(2*start))
            {
                for(k = j; (k < ((2*j) - 1)) && (k < length); k++)
                {
                    ParityCheck ^= (HammingString[length - k] - '0');
                } // End the k for-loop 
            } // End the j for-loop

                ErrorBit = ErrorBit + (ParityCheck * start);  
            } // End the i for-loop 

        if(ErrorBit == 0)
        {
            printf("No error \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("There is an error in bit: %d\n", ErrorBit);
            if(HammingString[length - ErrorBit] == '0')
            {
                HammingString[length - ErrorBit] = '1';
            } 
            else 
            {
                HammingString[length - ErrorBit] = '0';
            }

            printf("The corrected Hamming code is: %s \n", HammingString);
        } 
    } // End CheckHamming 

    int main()
    {

        int parity; 
        int choice = 0; 
            printf("Error detection/correction: \n");
            printf("----------------------------\n");
            printf("1) Enter parameters \n");
            printf("2) Check Hamming code \n");
            printf("3) Exit \n");
            printf("\nEnter selection: ");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            while (choice != 3)
            {
                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    EnterParameters(&MaxLength, &parity);
                    HammingString = (char*) malloc (MaxLength * sizeof(char));
                    main();
                }
                else if (choice == 2)
                {
                    CheckHamming(HammingString, parity);
                    main();
                }
                else 
                {
                    printf("Valid options are 1, 2, or 3. Quitting program. \n");
                    exit(0);
                }     
            }//end while
            exit(0);
    }//end main
```

If the hamming code: 1000110 is entered, the hand-calculated error comes out to an error in but 6 with the corrected code being 1100110. This code displays an error in bit 3 with the corrected code being 1000010. Any help is be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried another hand-written hamming code: 1000110 with no bit error while the above program is telling me that there is a bit error in bit 2 with the corrected code 1000011.

Comment: Umm, the code in the question `1000110` and the code in your comment `1000110` are exactly the same. So step 1 would seem to be to find a couple examples of codes where you actually know the correct answer.

Comment: That's my bad, perhaps I am didn't write the issue out correctly. I just ran the original hamming code. Input to check is 1000110. The correct answer is 1100110 with an error in bit 6. I am getting 1000010 with an error in bit 3. Is this what you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

I can't quite follow how your code is supposed to work. So here's a simple implementation that computes the syndrome for the code `1000110`. The output from the program is `6`, i.e. the error is in bit 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{               //  7654321
    char input[] = "1000110";
    int parity = 0;
    for ( int mask = 4; mask; mask >>= 1 )
    {
        for ( int bit = 1; bit <= 7; bit++ )
            if ( bit & mask )
                if ( input[7-bit] == '1' )
                    parity ^= mask;
    }
    printf( "%d\n", parity );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. My code is supposed to read in a string of any arbitrary length and calculate the hamming code on it. If there is no error, it should report that, if there is an error, it should report the bit value where it is and correct it. I am trying to figure out how to attach a working example as I have one as a point of reference.

Comment: Something like this: Enter the maximum length: 12
Enter the parity (0 = even, 1 = odd): 0 Enter selection: 2

Enter the Hamming code: 100011001010010
 
*** Invalid Entry - Exceeds Maximum Code Length of 12
Enter selection: 2

Enter the Hamming code: 1000110 

*** There is an error in bit: 6
*** The corrected Hamming code is: 1100110